# Showing graphs with php from Mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, image, dynamic-data

How can I show the statistics of data stored in a MySQL table dynamically with PHP image functions? I am able to show the counts in form of bar charts using count query on static tables but as shown in Image given. I have database that stores the logs of server dynamically.

The image is generated from 3 tables and image & draw functions of php

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how you are trying. But there is a nice Jquery plugin called Highcharts. You can use this to create various types of graphs. Please refer the below link if you are interested

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

Rgraph is also a very nice HTML5/Javascript Graph library, easy to use and with lots of options.

http://www.rgraph.net/

```
var data = ['<?php echo implode("','", $average); ?>']; 

function drawGraph(){
    RGraph.Clear(document.getElementById('myRadar'));
    var radar = new RGraph.Radar('myRadar', data);
```

This is how you can add a PHP array, $average is the array with the numbers, it's a radar chart in this example. The implode function puts a comma between the values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code create a simple bar chart with php.
You have to get the bar value from database and put it in $data array.
Next have to set the $height and $width for image size.
Based on your image size, you have to position the chat.

```
<?php

$data = array('400', '2570', '245', '473', '1000', '3456', '780', '5000', '30', '420');
$sum = array_sum($data);

$height = 480;
$width  = 640;

$im         = imagecreate($width, $height);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

$white  = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$red    = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$green  = imagecolorallocate($im, 51, 153, 0);
$yellow = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);

imageline($im, 10, 5, 10, $height - 20, $black);
imageline($im, 10, $height - 20, 620, $height - 20, $black);

header("Content-type: image/png");

$x       = 11;
$y       = 459;
$x_width = 20;
$y_ht    = 0;

$max_i = count($data);
for ($i     = 0; $i < $max_i; $i++) {
    $y_ht = ($data[$i] / $sum) * $height;
    if ($data[$i] > 1000) {
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $x_width, ($y - $y_ht), $green);
    } else if ($data[$i] > 500) {
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $x_width, ($y - $y_ht), $yellow);
    } else {
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $x_width, ($y - $y_ht), $red);
    }
    imagestring($im, 2, $x - 1, ($y - $y_ht - 15), $data[$i], $black);
    $x += ($x_width + 2);
}
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

ref: http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1629-bar-chart-php.html